# Asp.Net Boilerplate Entity notifications

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have Notifications working in a .NET Core web application. However I'm trying to understand the Entity Notification operation. As I read the documentation and tried few coding some scenarios it doesn't seem to be working as I thought it might.  My application has a Table for "Parcels". I created a Subscription based on one of the Parcels listed in the table

```
await _notificationSubscriptionManager
    .SubscribeAsync(new UserIdentifier(tenantId, userId), "ParcelTransfer", new EntityIdentifier(typeof(Parcel), 3041));
```

The Id Value I used is the Id value for a Parcel in the Parcel database table. The code then then fires a publish call but uses a different Parcel Id value

```
await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync(notificationName, data: new MessageNotificationData(message), 
                    new EntityIdentifier(typeof(Parcel), 3042), userIds: userIds);
```

However, I still receive a Notification. I thought because I issued the Publish call using a different Parcel Identity Id value, a Notification would NOT be sent.  I'm thinking I don't understand how the process works.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I didn't need to specify an `EntityIdentifier` object in the `PublishAsync()` method. The fact the ***User*** with a ***Tenant*** and ***UserId*** was specified in the ***Subscription*** `SubscribeAsync()` method was all I needed.

When the publish command was issued, the code just needed to look at the ***Subscriptions*** based on the subscription name.

I also had to modify my ***EmailRealTimeNotifier*** class for both methods `SendNotifications()` and `SendNotificationsAsync()` to

```
 [UnitOfWork]
    public void SendNotifications(UserNotification[] userNotifications)
    {
     
        foreach (var userNotification in userNotifications)
        {
            if (userNotification.Notification.Data is MessageNotificationData data)
            {

                using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(userNotification.TenantId))
                {
                    var user =  _userManager.GetUserById(userNotification.UserId);

                    _emailSender.Send(
                        to: user.EmailAddress,
                        subject: "You have a new notification!",
                        body: data.Message,
                        isBodyHtml: true
                    );
                }

            }
        }
    }
```